# How do you remove the first few lines of a CSV?

Tags: javascript, csv

I am getting a CSV from a remote source that I need to change to JSON. Given a header and data I can do this using the csvtojson library. Unfortunately the CSV comes with 3 rows of descriptive information then a blank row.  I need to remove these first four rows so that my csvtojson will work correctly. For example:

```
Report Name,First Report
Date Run,7/25/16
Filters,Transaction Date >= 7/1/16,Transaction Date <= 7/25/16,Network = US Network,Time Zone = GM

Clicks,Baseline Commission,Browser,Click IP Address
1,0,"Chrome 52.0.2743.82","67.180.103.3"
```

I need to remove the lines beginning with "Report", "Date" and "Filters".

Comment: you're fetching the entire csv as a string? if so, you can just strip off the unwanted lines.

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: @Marc B It's coming in as a proper CSV file as shown in the spec: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#header-configuration

Comment: @hindmost - I'm not sure where to go from here. I was first told that I'd have to figure out how to get a CSV to the DB in a world where I had only worked with JSON before. I figured that part out based on a faulty example the source gave me which did not include the additional information. I'm not sure where to go from here and that's why I came to SO.

Comment: Yeah, if you're getting the data as a string, then you can just remove the first three lines (or you can even check where the headers end). If you are actually opening a file using Node.JS, then I'm not sure how you do that (never had to), but there must be a way to start reading from a given line or move the file pointer or maybe read by line and discard input.

Comment: @Vld, I'm pretty sure it's a .csv file I'm receiving and not a string. Could I perhaps change it to a string first? How would I do that?

Comment: if you have the entire csv as string, removing first 3 line is as simple as locating the index of first occurrence of 2 newlines and taking a substring from that index.. Eg: var stripped = csvString.substr(csvString.indexOf("\n\n")); New line varies depending on the OS that generates the CSV